# Cancel is not working in Activity to cancel a particular Push notification android

Tags: android, push-notification

Here I'm showing a push notifications in android from`Service` class which is showing fine and getting dismiss if we tap on complete `Remoteview` but when I'm opening an `Activity` from buttons/texts of `RemoteView`, notifications don't get cancelled.

In Service:

```
Intent notificationRecordFollowupintent = new Intent(this, RecordFollowUpActivity.class);
notificationRecordFollowupintent.putExtra("notify_id", m);
PendingIntent contentRecordFollowupIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, m, notificationRecordFollowupintent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_SOUND)
                .setStyle(bigTextStyle)
                .setCustomBigContentView(contentView)
                .setCustomContentView(contentView)
                .setGroup("Follow Up Alert")
                .setNumber(++numMessages)
                .setOngoing(true)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentIntent(contentRecordFollowupIntent);
    } else {
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("Follow Up Alert")
                .setContentText("" + name)
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_SOUND)
                .setStyle(bigTextStyle)
                .setCustomContentView(contentView)
                .setCustomBigContentView(contentView)
                .setContentIntent(contentRecordFollowupIntent)
                .setAutoCancel(true);

    }

    Notification notification = builder.build();
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    nm.notify(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name), m, notification);
```

In Activity:

```
 Intent intent = getIntent();
    int notificationId = intent.getIntExtra("notify_id", -1);
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.cancel(notificationId);
```

I'm getting same Id also still it doesn't get cancelled.

Comment: Can you share your code that creates the notification? Does it use the same ID as variable `m` in the Service? You are using `m` for the `requestCode` of the PendingIntent, but I can't see if `m` is being used for the actual `notificationId` on `notificationManager.notify()`.

Comment: Sure, check my updated question

Comment: Thanks, that seems like it should work! How does the service decide when to create a notification? Could it be recreating it quicker than it can be cancelled?

Comment: are you using startForground() ?

Comment: @Grimthorr yea, I insert userId into db first time when i show notification and second time I check into db first if its there I don't send notifications. And It gets cancelled when I tap on `RemoteView` but not on its buttons.

Comment: @ADM no foreground. Does it need ?

Comment: startForground services mostly used by Music player apps .In your case it seems the you don't need it .
Check if notification Id is Same and try to remove tag from notify. form this line "nm.notify(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name), m, notification);"

Comment: I checked that and I found that it was same Id in cancel method what was going through `PendingIntent`

Comment: @AnshulTyagi Did you find the solution? I'm having a similar kind of problem here.

Answer (score -1):

`NotificationManager.cancelAll()` to remove all notification. `NotificationManager.cancel(notificationId)` to remove particular notification.